# Having issues trying to create multiple users for this API?

Tags: php, api, postman

I'm able to post the creation of one user through Postman, but I'm having trouble adjusting this code so that I can post the creation of multiple users. I've tried to create a foreach loop but couldn't get it to work so I scrapped it. If someone could please help me, I'd be really thankful.

This is the code for createOne.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../class/users.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$item = new users($db);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$item->user_id = $data->user_id;
$item->user_name = $data->user_name;
$item->age = $data->age;
$item->birthday = date('YYYY-MM-DD');
$item->gender = $data->gender;

if($item->createUser()){
    echo 'User created successfully.';
} else{
    echo 'User could not be created.';
}
?>
```

And this is the users.php

```
<?php
class users{

    // Connection
    private $conn;

    // Table
    private $db_table = "users";

    // Columns
    public $user_id;
    public $user_name;
    public $age;
    public $birthday;
public $gender;


    // Db connection
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }
    
    // CREATE
    public function createUser(){
        $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO
                        ". $this->db_table ."
                    SET
                        user_id = :user_id, 
                        user_name = :user_name, 
                        age = :age, 
                        birthday = :birthday, 
gender = :gender";
                        

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sqlQuery);

        // sanitize
        $this->user_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->user_id));
        $this->user_name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->user_name));
        $this->age=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->age));
        $this->birthday=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->birthday));
        $this->gender=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->gender));


        // bind data
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $this->user_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_name", $this->user_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":age", $this->age);
        $stmt->bindParam(":birthday", $this->birthday);
        $stmt->bindParam(":gender", $this->gender);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
?>
```

This is what I tried to do in the createOne file:

```
foreach ((array) $data as $key=>$value) {
    $item->user_id = $data->user_id;
$item->user_name = $data->user_name;
$item->age = $data->age;
$item->birthday = date('YYYY-MM-DD');
$item->gender = $data->gender;

if($item->createUser()){
echo 'User created successfully.';
} 
else{
echo 'User could not be created.';
}

}
```

And whenever I try to post new users through Postman, I get this:

```
"Notice:  Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object in ..."
"Notice:  Trying to get property 'user_name' of non-object in ..."
"Notice:  Trying to get property 'age' of non-object in ..."
"Notice:  Trying to get property 'birthday' of non-object in ..."
"Notice:  Trying to get property 'gender' of non-object in ..."
"User could not be created"
```

(Ex: When I try to post 3 new users, I get the response above 3 times because of the loop)

Comment: Should just be a case of looping. What exactly went wrong, what did you try?

Comment: @ADyson Hi, I've updated the post with what I tried and the error I'm getting at the end.

Comment: What JSON did you send to the script? Please show that too

Comment: Add a line `error_log('data: ' . var_export($data, true));` before your loop. Trigger your API call, then check your server logs to see the actual data structure.